# Can not use <a> tag to link to a position on the same page

Tags: html

I use  tag in html to jump to a position of page, but it just jump to 1 position uniquely in firefox, in chrome it can run aswell

```
<a href="#position1">
<a href="#position2">
<a href="#position3">

<a id="position1">position 1</a>
<a id="position2">position 2</a>
<a id="position3">position 3</a>
```

I put `position 1,2,3` at different position on the same page

In chrome it works. But I having trouble with Firefox when I click any position link, it all jump to a position (**I.E.** position 2).
how can I fix it?

Comment: What's your doctype please?

Comment: I don't know why this link http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ramaria_botrytis#Description can work , but my link cannot work http://dienmay.com/san-hang-tu-quy#tuquy1

Answer (score 1):

I think you want to jump to divs not anchor tags.

```
<a href="#position1">
<a href="#position2">
<a href="#position3">

<div id="position1">position 1</div>
<div id="position2">position 2</div>
<div id="position3">position 3</div>
```

**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/danield770/qM2BU/)**

Comment: I try div first , but it is not work , and I use <a> instead

Comment: I added a fiddle for you in the answer

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you will "jump" into form tags, since you set `<a>` tags in your code and firefox might having a lite confuse with this pirticular code.

**Here is my solution:**

```
<a href="#poisition1">test1</a>
<a href="#poisition2">test2</a>
<a href="#poisition3">test3</a>

<form id="position1">text 1</form>
<form id="position2">text 2</form>
<form id="position3">text 3</form>
```

So I was trying out some codes and I've figured out that you need a large space from each form part.

Here is a [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qM2BU/1/)

Comment: I don't want to view the target position on this page. You can view my product at this link   http://dienmay.com/san-hang-tu-quy   , my idea of the jumping position is not work on the firefox

Comment: @CuongLe In that case i would suggest to add action method to form tag.

Comment: I try form tag, but it is not work on firefox

Comment: @CuongLe I've edited.

Answer (score 0):

Updated code (after finding out `name` in anchors is obsolete .. wasn't aware of that)

```
<a href="#position1">1</a>
<a href="#position2">2</a>
<a href="#position3">3</a>

<div id="position1">
    <a href="..">...</a>
</div>
<div id="position2">
    <a href="..">...</a>
</div>
<div id="position3">
    <a href="..">...</a>
</div>
```

Old answer was:

> As far as I know, this behavior is linked to the `name` attribute
>
> This should work:
>
> ```
> <a href="#position1">1</a>
> <a href="#position2">2</a>
> <a href="#position3">3</a>
>
> <a name="position1">position 1</a>
> <a name="position2">position 2</a>
> <a name="position3">position 3</a>
> ```
>
> Note: this also works with `<div name="...">` if you prefer

Comment: @CuongLe If you are using HTML5 this attribute is obsolete. That's the reason I  have asked you this in the comments.